# Form values variables and submission problems

Tags: php, webforms, form-submit

Can someone help me fix this code? What I want to fix is:

If a person doesn't enter a username or password, I just want the error text (the red messages on the side) without the 'sorry, no access' message on top.

Also, if a person gains access (or doesn't), I want the text fields and submit button go away.

This isn't going to be a real form, so please don't worry about how I'm using a username and password....and if its possible do you think most of my code could stay the same?

Thanks!

```
    <?php
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        .error
        {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>';

    $error = false;

    if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {

    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
    {
    $error = TRUE;
    }

    if (!$error && $_POST['username']=='test' && $_POST['password']=='abc123') {

    echo '<p>Correct. Thank you for entering.<p/>';
    }

    else
    {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no access.</p>
    ';
     }

     }
     ?>
     <form action="" method="post">
     Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="20" value="<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && !empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        echo $_POST['username'];
    } ?>" />
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        echo '<span class="error">Please enter a username.</span>';
    }
    ?>
    <br />Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20" value="<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        echo $_POST['password'];
    } ?>" />
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        echo '<span class="error">Please enter a password.</span>';
    }
    ?>
   <br /><input type="submit" value="Log in" />
   <br /><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.error {
color: red;
}
</style>
<?php

$submitted  = isset($_POST['submitted']);
$userName   = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
$password   = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

if($submitted) {
    if (!$userName || !$password) {
        echo '<p class="error">Please go back and fill the inputs.</p>';
    } elseif($userName == 'test' && $password == 'abc123') {
        echo '<p>Correct. Thank you for entering.<p/>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">Sorry, no access.</p>';
    }
} else {
?>
<form action="" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="20" value="<?php echo $userName; ?>" />
<br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20" value="" />
<br /><input type="submit" value="Log in" />
<br /><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: while that does work (and thanks by the way), is there anyway to just have the individual error messages i had appear next to the input fields? Thats ultimately what I want and of course, is the hardest thing for me to do! LOL

Comment: @Reki Sorry, that's your job. This is Q & A site, not programming farm.

Comment: i thought my problems were the 'q' of q and a! I'm not asking for someone to write something for me from scratch...I've worked my issues out as best as I could and I'm honestly just looking to be pushed in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the onSubmit event on your form.

You need to combine php and javascript here in order to prevent it from submitting. Make a Jscript function that's called by onSubmit. If a value isn't filled in, return false. It'll kill the submit button and print out directly on the screen.

So just take this:

```
$submitted  = isset($_POST['submitted']);
$userName   = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
$password   = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

if($submitted)
{
     if (!$userName || !$password) {
        echo '<p class="error">Please go back and fill the inputs.</p>';
    }
}
```

And then on your form:
`<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="checkForm()">`

Then figure out how you're going to check the form with javascript. You can piece together the rest.